# Set list item tag to [*]x instead of [li]x[/li] in SCEditor for vBulletin compatibility

Tags: javascript, bbcode, vbulletin, sceditor

### TL;DR

SCEditor uses `[li]test[/li]` for list items. To make it compatible for VB, I want to change this to `[*]test`. But my approach doesn't full work. I can make the editor to insert `[*]` for list items. However they always contain an unwanted line break before their content.

**So the question is: How can I change `[li]x[/li]` to `[*]x` without the line break after `[*]` of my current solution (see above)?**

### Detailled explanation and my approach

I want SCEditor to be compatible with VBulletin. Many BBCodes works but lists doesn't. When creating a list in SCEditor, it generates the following BBCode:

```
[ul]
[li]x[/li]
[li]y[/li]
[/ul]
```

VBulletin doesn't parse this since it uses `[list]` instead of `[ul]`. By understand [bbcode.js](https://github.com/samclarke/SCEditor/blob/master/src/formats/bbcode.js#L438) I could fix this by replacing the format of the BBCode:

```
sceditor.formats.bbcode.set('ul', {
    tags: {
        ul: null
    },
    breakStart: true,
    isInline: false,
    skipLastLineBreak: true,
    format: '[list]{0}[/list]',
    html: '<ul>{0}</ul>'
})
```

But when I change 
But the `[li]x[/li]` also doesn't work since VB uses `[*] x` without closing tag. Tried modifing this item too:

```
sceditor.formats.bbcode.remove('li')
sceditor.formats.bbcode.set('li', {
    tags: {
        li: null,
        '*': null
    },
    isInline: false,
    excludeClosing: true,
    isSelfClosing: true,
    skipLastLineBreak: true,
    closedBy: ['/ul', '/ol', '/list', '*', 'li'],
    format: '[*]{0}',
    html: '<li>{0}</li>'
})
sceditor.formats.bbcode.remove('*')
sceditor.formats.bbcode.set('*', {
    isInline: false,
    //excludeClosing: true,
    isSelfClosing: true,
    //skipLastLineBreak: true,
    html: '<li>{0}</li>'
})
```

Now when pressing the list button, the editor inserts BBCodes nearly as I need them:

```
[list]
[*]
x[/list]
```

Since it creates a line break between `[*]` and the content, it looks broken:

[image]

It seems that `li` is used for the editor controls (insert list button), where `*` (last entry) handles the parsing from BBCode to Editor HTML (when toggling between source code and WYSIWYG view).

Answer (score 1):

Found out that I need setting `isSelfClosing` to `false` in `*` BBCode. `skipLastLineBreak` is not required as well as deleting the tag with `sceditor.formats.bbcode.remove('*')` since `set()` overrides any existing tags (described in the documentation).

The following works:

```
sceditor.formats.bbcode.set('*', {
    isInline: false,
    // Avoid automatically closing tag [/*]
    excludeClosing: true,
    // Avoids line break between [*] and list point content
    isSelfClosing: false,
    html: '<li>{0}</li>'
})
```

Results in

```
[list]
[*]x
[*]y
[/list]
```